# assigning a value to a variable with .attr

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, href, attr

I am attempting to take all anchor elements with an href value beginning with "/ric", which are local links, and then add onto the beginning the missing domain info.

For some reason it is not allowing me to set the value of originalHref at all (or so it seems, tried debugging by using "alert(originalHref);" after the variable was declared and I do not get anything returned).

```
$('a[href^="/ric"]').each(function(){ 
       var originalHref = $(this).attr("href");
       this.href = this.href.replace(href, 'http://www.test.com' + originalHref);
    };
});
```

Comment: Why don't you do `$(this).attr("href", 'http://www.test.com' + originalHref);`?

Answer (score 1):

this is what you're looking for:

```
$(this).attr('href','http://www.test.com'+originalHerf);
```

you could remove a line by doing this instead:

```
$(this).attr('href','http://www.test.com'+$(this).attr('href'));
```

Comment: Appreciate all the quick responses, I have changed the script to remove the variable line and used the second line you suggest here, however it still is just attempting to open those links as local links which of course does not work... any other thoughts as to why it might not work?

Comment: @user2153957 That's strange... try this to see if the url is a valid url: `console.log('http://www.test.com'+$('a[href^="/ric"]').attr('href');`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a[href^="/ric"]').each(function(){ 
    $(this).attr('href', 'http://www.test.com' + $(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).attr('href','http://www.test.com'+$(this).attr('href'));
```

**Syntax;**

```
$(selector).attr(attribute,value);
```

it will work

Answer (score 0):

Try this option:

```
$('a[href^="/ric"]').attr( "href", function(){ 
   return ('http://www.test.com' + $(this).attr('href'));
});
```

**[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/ym6ZN/)**

Comment: I have tried this line for line and when the links are clicked it is still tryin to open the links locally, rather than adding the 'http://www.test.com' to open them correctly. Any other thoughts as to what might be wrong here?

Comment: What is you local url..? Have you tried logging : `'http://www.test.com' + $('a[href^="/ric"]').attr('href')`
 to console to see what happens...?

Comment: I am using windows sharepoint to access content from my companies intraweb, however all of the links on that content are local, so when I click on them inside sharepoint, they are trying to open as <'https://appservicesstd.wss.bank.com/ric...'> and I need them to open as <'http://rcbpt.bank.com/ric...'>

Comment: @user2153957 : Try with `$('a[href*="/ric"]')` instead of `$('a[href^="/ric"]')` and see if there is any change..

Comment: no change, still have the wrong domain when I click a link within the content

Comment: just thinking out loud here, but would it possibly work to have this function happen whenever a link is clicked, and then have it redirect to the full url?

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery selector for the href ^= will only look for elements that start with /ric in the URL.

If you have a URL that is www.google.com/ric that will not match the selector and won't change the href attribute using the jQuery provided above.

Note that the answers that have been given all work based on the href starting with /ric

If you examine the page source and find the anchor tag that your trying to change and examine the href attribute.  Does it have a relative ( '/ric' ) or absolute ('https://appservicesstd.wss.bank.com/ric') URL?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).attr('href','http://www.test.com',$(this).attr('href'));
```

Its my test code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function (){ 
            $('button').click(function(){
               var text = $('.qwerty').html();
            });
        $(".qwerty1").attr('dir',$('.qwerty').html());
        });

        </script>
        <div class="qwerty">123</div>
        <div class="qwerty1" dir=""></div>
```

I hope I helped you.